# Scrapy - Change Itemloader behavior to keep fields that are "empty"

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

How do I change the default scrapy itemloader behavior so it doesn't remove Nones or 0 valued fields in processing? I know that's what's going on here from reading some things and testing a few things. In my research, I've been looking over the docs and the github repo and I can't seem to find anything that would let me control this. Right now, I've been using -1 as a value instead of zero to indicate when something is 0, but this seems suboptimal.

Mostly, what I'm looking for is a way to tune the settings of itemloader so I can do what I want (or if it's impossible, to tell it to me straight).

Current (working code)

```py
Compose(lambda v: v[0].split()[0] if v else "-1", int) # if none; then -1
```

What I'd like to work :(

```py
Compose(lambda v: v[0].split()[0] if v else "0", int) # if none; then -0
```

Update: I found some hints about this in the [github repo](https://github.com/scrapy/itemloaders/blob/master/itemloaders/processors.py) and in some [old docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/1.8/topics/loaders.html) which seem to explain this behavior. Like I've read elsewhere and seen, the itemloaders drop none values (including 0s) by default.

**Quote from Github:**

"
By default, stop process on `None` value. This behaviour can be changed by
passing keyword argument `stop_on_none=False`."

**Quotes from docs:**

"By default, stop process on None value. This behaviour can be changed by passing keyword argument stop_on_none=False."

"Each function can optionally receive a loader_context parameter. For those which do, this processor will pass the currently active Loader context through that parameter."

"The keyword arguments passed in the constructor are used as the default Loader context values passed to each function call. However, the final Loader context values passed to functions are overridden with the currently active Loader context accessible through the ItemLoader.context() attribute."

I've tried a few different ways of modifying that (all found on the old docs). It doesn't throw an error so it's accepting my keyword but it's not using it it seems.

```py
Compose(lambda v: v[0].split()[0] if v else "0", int, stop_on_none=False)

comment_loader = ItemLoader(item=comment(), selector=article, stop_on_none=False) # does not work

comment_loader.context["stop_on_none"] = False # does not work
```

I *think* my current issue is that I'm running into the active loader context but I can't quite figure out what I tried doesn't work given what I've seen in the (admittedly old) doc and github.

Update:
Further digging into the issues on the github repo (and elsewhere) tells me that the issue is in the design of the library. It drops any None values and it would seem it also drops 0 values. There doesn't seem to be a way to work around this right now as evidenced [here](https://github.com/scrapy/itemloaders/issues/40). It also seems like this won't be changed in the future (for fear of breaking projects in the wild).

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way would be to subclass the processor that you want to override and reimplement it's `__call__` method so that it processes None and empty values in a different way.  And if the value isn't None or empty then you can pass the values to the superclass to process.

For example:

```
class CustomCompose(Compose):
    def __call__(self, value, loader_context=None):
        if not value:
            return 0
        return super().__call__(value, loader_context=loader_context)

v = CustomCompose(lambda v: v[0].split()[0], int)
print(v(None))
print(v([]))
```

**Output**

```
0
0
```